# Check if provided location info from fused location provider is from GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

We are using [fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) and if I query `location.getProvider()` on the location I'm receiving it returns `fused`. I would like to check whether the fused provider used GPS or Wifi or both for the location it gave me. is this possible? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fused provider does not provide you with the specific location provider it only returns `fused` as you said, if you want to listen for a specific provider you need to use the old `LocationManager`