# android.location.LocationManager's onLocationChanged is never called

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have a service that provides location updates to the rest of the app. I was using fused location provider from google play services but [I need to know the actual provider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25558761/558991) so I went with android's `LocationManager` instead. the problem is, the `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` is never called, `onProviderEnabled` and `onProviderDisabled` do get called.

**MyService (extends Service implements LocationListener) onCreate():**

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
```

......

```
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = buildCriteria();
    List<String> bestProviders = locationManager.getProviders(criteria, true); // returns 'gps' on test device
    Log.d(TAG, "Found " + bestProviders.size() + " providers");
    try {
      for (String provider : bestProviders) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  private Criteria buildCriteria() {
    Criteria res = new Criteria();
    res.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    res.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    res.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    res.setBearingRequired(false);
    res.setCostAllowed(false);
    res.setSpeedRequired(false);

    return res;
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="ee.mtakso.driver.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
```

I'm testing on LG G3 with Android 4.4.2, GPS, LTE and Wifi are on.

Comment: Try using the Google Play Location Manager. There are some known issues with LocationManager on some handsets.

Comment: Can you see a small gps icon blinking in the notification area??if yes that means your gps has not been fixed.So to fix it please show your mobile device to open sky for two minutes or so.You;ll will see that the blinking stops and it gets fixed..Try it..

Comment: @hoomi the fused location manager does not return the provider that the location was received with which is what the OP wants

Comment: @Lal the gps works fine, it is fixed and works in other apps.

Comment: try replacing `this` with your Listener in requestLocationUpdates()

Comment: If you are requesting from multiple sources, they may be overlapping. Try just requesting from one source, the first in your list.

Comment: @Breadbin I don't think requesting from multiple sources cause any problems, also currently the list has only "gps" so it's a single source.

Comment: @Lal tried it, no luck :/

Comment: Try adding this permission too..`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`